# Azure DevOps Build Pipeline: How to enforce StyleCop for a .Net Core app in the Build Pipeline?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have the following Azure DevOps Pipeline for a .Net Core app. This pipeline works without any issue. Now, I want to enforce StyleCop in the Build Pipeline. How do I do it?

Here is my Yaml file

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main

stages:
  - stage: build_and_deploy_to_dev
    jobs:
      - deployment: DeployToDev
        displayName: Deploy to dev
        pool:
          vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"
        environment: tenant-service-dev
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - checkout: self
                - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
                  displayName: Execute Unit Tests
                  inputs:
                    command: test
                    projects: "**/UnitTests/**/*.UnitTests.csproj"
                - task: Docker@2
                  displayName: Build And Push Image to Container Registry
                  inputs:
                    containerRegistry: $(DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVICE_CONNECTION)
                    repository: $(IMAGE_REPOSITORY)
                    command: "buildAndPush"
                    buildContext: "./"
                    Dockerfile: "**/src/Tenant.Api/Dockerfile"
                    tags: |
                      $(TAG)
                      latest  
                - task: Kubernetes@1
                  displayName: Deploy to Dev Kubernetes Cluster
                  inputs:
                    connectionType: Azure Resource Manager
                    azureSubscriptionEndpoint: $(SERVICE_CONNECTION_DEV_)
                    azureResourceGroup: $(RESOURCE_GROUP_DEV)
                    kubernetesCluster: $(K8S_CLUSTER_DEV)
                    command: set
                    arguments: image deployment/$(APP_NAME_DEV) $(K8S_CONTAINER_NAME)=$(CONTAINER_REGISTRY_)/$(IMAGE_REPOSITORY):$(TAG)  --namespace=$(K8S_NAMESPACE)
```

Comment: Do you have `<EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>True</EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>` in your .csproj files?

Comment: Yes, I did. <EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>True</EnforceCodeStyleInBuild> in the.csproj files

Comment: Code analysis is limited to .NET versions and to whom the project is targeted. If your project meets [these conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/configuration-options#enable-code-analysis), you need to set `<EnableNETAnalyzers>true</EnableNETAnalyzers>`. Please refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/overview?tabs=net-7#enable-on-build) to enable code style analysis when building.